# Chartjs - different shadow for each Arc

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Is it possible with [ChartJs](https://www.chartjs.org/) to style each Doughnut Chart Arc with different drop shadow?

[image]

I've made some customisation in `beforeDraw` hook:

```
chart.data.datasets.forEach(((set) => {
        set.backgroundColor.forEach((bgColor) => {
            const _stroke = ctx.stroke;
            ctx.stroke = function () {
                ctx.save();
                ctx.shadowColor = bgColor;
                ctx.shadowBlur = 10;
                ctx.shadowOffsetX = 2;
                ctx.shadowOffsetY = 2;
                _stroke.apply(this, arguments);
                ctx.restore();
            };

            const _fill = ctx.fill;
            ctx.fill = function () {
                ctx.save();
                ctx.shadowColor = bgColor;
                ctx.shadowBlur = 10;
                ctx.shadowOffsetX = 2;
                ctx.shadowOffsetY = 2;
                _fill.apply(this, arguments);
                ctx.restore();
            };
        });
    }));
```

But it seems like the last color from data is being aplied:

[image]

Comment: Curious to know if you did it

Comment: @GuilhermeFelipeReis sadly nope :( It was super time consuming and decided to mix it with css